# select first order for each customer from two tables

Tags: t-sql

Hi guys I have two tables dbo.Sales (customer_id, order_date, product_id) and dbo.Menu (Product_id, product_name, price). The question is
What was the first item from the menu purchased by each customer?

My solution is

```
    select A.customer_id,m.product_id, m.product_name
    from dbo.menu  m
    cross apply
    (select top 1 * from dbo.sales s
    where s.product_id=m.product_id
    group by s.customer_id,s.order_date, s.product_id
    order by s.order_date) A
```

customer_id product_id  product_name
A       1            sushi
A       2            curry
C       3            ramen

Missing customer is B. Instead of B it gives me the second first order by A.

I need for each customer

Murat

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. "What was the first item from the menu" means the lowest `product_id` value or alphabetically by `product_name` for the earliest date? Are you authorized to provide the DDL so that we don't have to guess whether `order_date` is a `smalldatetime`, `nvarchar(max)` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to get the earliest `product_id` per customer and then join to the `Menu` table to get your product details.

Edit: Updated `ORDER` to `ASC`.

```
;with cte
as (
select customer_id, product_id, row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by order_date acs) RN
from dbo.Sales)
select c.customer_id, c.product_id, m.product_name
from cte c
join dbo.menu m on c.product_id=m.product_id
where RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but it gives right answer only for C. The others are wrong.  'A 3 ramen
B 3 ramen
C 3 ramen'

Comment: Looks like the order by in row_number() should be ASC instead of DESC for Order_date for RN

Comment: @KevinJohnson Yep, you're right.  I've updated that in my code.  Thanks.

Comment: @Murat My code is updated above with the correct Order.  Give it a try now.

Comment: @Murat If this works for you, could you please accept and upvote the answer?  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT distinct s.customer_id,
FIRST_VALUE(m.product_name) OVER (partition by s.customer_id order by order_date )
as  FirstItem_Customer
FROM [dbo].[sales] S
join [dbo].[menu] M on M.product_id=s.product_id